# TIME INTEGRAL PROBLEM: Taking an integral of a growth-rates-form equation with respect to time

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, logarithms, economics

I am trying to solve the following problem as described here:
https://www.adb.org/publications/total-factor-productivity-testing-growth-models (pages 4-5)
http://digamo.free.fr/macombie98.pdf (pages 165-166)

It all starts with this accounting identity:

[accounting identity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKyFD.png)

The equation is transformed so that it can be expressed in growth rates of the corresponding variables.
If we suppose that *a* is a constant and that both *w* and *r* grow at constant exponential rates, we can **integrate** the iquation and it should yield this:

$$
Y_t = A_0 \exp (\lambda t)L_t^a K_t^{1-a}
$$

Does anybody know the exact steps taken while integrating the growth-rates-form equation?

Thank you

Comment: I had asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2954054/pde-to-obtain-function-x-y-mapsto-c-x-alpha-y1-alpha).

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be wanting to integrate $A \exp(\lambda t)L^a_tK^{1-a}_t$.  That depends strongly on exactly how $L^a_t$ and $K^{1-a}_t$ depend on t and I could not find that in your links.

Comment: Perhaps this helps: http://college.holycross.edu/RePEc/eej/Archive/Volume31/V31N3P427_445.pdf (page 433)

Comment: I believe we are supposed to apply this rule of integration ∫(u′/u)dt=ln|u|+C but I might be wrong

Comment: similarly to here... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/919432/integral-respect-to-time?rq=1